# Plot Two arrays Values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, plot

so, i have tried to `Plot` all of values of `(h,rex)`

but its `plot` just the last values of them.

i think must use `array` but i dont know how to do that. i hope to help me !

```
        clc

Pr=1.05;
lam=0.167;
l=2;
rex=100;
while (rex<2900) 
disp('rex');
disp(rex);
h=((0.664*Pr^(1/3)*lam)/l)*rex^(1/2) ;
disp('h');
disp(h);
rex=rex+100;
end
plot(rex,h);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not storing your intermediate values, hence `rex` and `h` are overwritten each time and only the values from the last iteration are available. Solve this by storing the values in an array:

```
Pr=1.05;
lam=0.167;
l=2;
rex=100;

rex_array = [];
h_array = [];
while (rex<2900) 
    h=((0.664*Pr^(1/3)*lam)/l)*rex^(1/2) ;
    rex=rex+100;
    % store values in array (appending)
    rex_array(end+1) = rex;
    h_array(end+1) = h;
end

figure(1); clf;
plot(rex_array,h_array);
```

This is not recommended though, since `rex_array` and `h_array` are increasing in size with every iteration. So instead you use a for loop.

```
rex = 100:100:2900; % or to give same result as the while loop: 100:100:2800
h = zeros(size(rex)); % initialize h to be a zero vector with the same size as rex

% loop over rex
for k = 1:numel(rex) 
    % store each value in h(k):
    h(k)=((0.664*Pr^(1/3)*lam)/l)*rex(k)^(1/2) ;
end

figure(1); clf;
plot(rex,h);
```

The best option though is to avoid the loop completely, and use vectorization:

```
rex = 100:100:2900; % or to give same result as the while loop: 100:100:2800
h=((0.664*Pr^(1/3)*lam)/l)*rex.^(1/2);
```

By using `.^` each element in `rex` will be squared element wise.